# Determining whether a string is a math formula?

Tags: regex, string, math, filter, formula

So I'm processing math formulas from strings using the shunting-yard algorithm. I pass every string through a function which processes specific strings into values, but occasionally I check against strings that are just strings that should just get passed by - read skip the shunting-yard pass. Should I just use a regular expression to test for all of the symbols and numbers? Or is there a simpler way I might test for this? I guess the inverse would be checking if there are still any letters left in the string?

Comment: Ah, Math can be so irregular!

Comment: What's the result of running those "non-formulas" through shunting-yard? Does it abort with an exception? If so, this *might* be the correct way to handle it: simply try to interpret everything. If it fails, it's not a formula.

Comment: You can't use regex for this. Well-balanced expressions do ***not*** form a regular language.

Comment: Re Alex C.: I don't see how this isn't filterable? For my purposes, if the string contains +-/*(), it's a math problem. Since I'm pre-filtering for strings which represent values, if any strings remain, that seems like the best option at this point. If you care to further clarify?

Comment: Re J. Sauer: Right now, it throws exception. Rather than altering the shunting-yard class, I was thinking to filter beforehand.

Comment: Alex:  regex is just a filtering technique.  "Well-balanced" math expressions just conform to some syntax.  A filtering technique is perfectly capable of checking whether some string conforms to some syntax and returning a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure there is a better answer, I've decided to use the following until something better comes up, I'm working in AS3:

```
if ( !String( value ).match( /[a-zA-Z]/ ) && !String( value ).match( /^(-?\d+)$/ ) && String( value ).match( /[()\\*+-]/ ) )
{
    value = MathParser.parse( value );
}
```

The first expression verifies that there are no characters - my shunting yard implementation doesn't process special characters or operations, it just does basic math, so if there are any characters remaining, something is wrong.

The second verifies that the string contains mathmatical symbols. There's no point in attempting the operation if there's no math to process. I assume this is unnecessary if I wanted to handle errors inside the shunting-yard processes.

And finally I verify that the value isn't just a standalone number of positive or negative value.

Comments for improvement appreciated.

Comment: I think we'd need access to the rest of your code.  For example, your if() doesn't check to find whether the string contains any numbers at all, and we can't see what sort of errors the MathParser.parse() will return. Without the other part, we wouldn't know which parts of error checking is still missing. Also, do you want to determine whether a given string is a valid math function before sending the string to MathParser.parse()?  Or do you want your error handling to be performed in a mixture of places?  Finally, what language is this?